# My code can not select from a list by xpath

Tags: cypress

Using this website https://mawadda-eg.com/home
am trying to select birthdate in profile but no selection occurs

```js
   it('EditData1',function(){
     cy.login();
   
        cy.get('#header > div > nav > div.tt-menu-collapse.tt-submenu-dark > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a').click();
        cy.wait(10000);
        cy.contains('الصفحة الشخصية' ,{timeout:10000}).should('be.visible');
        cy.wait(10000);
        cy.get('#user-info-contact-form > div > div:nth-child(8) > div > div > div.col-md-8 > button').click();
        cy.wait(10000);
     
        //select gender
        cy.xpath('/html/body/app-root/div/div/div/app-demographics-modal/div/div/div/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/label[1]/input',{force: true}).click();
        //select mariyal
        cy.xpath('/html/body/app-root/div/div/div/app-demographics-modal/div/div/div/form/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/label[3]/input',{force: true}).click();
        //select birthdate
        cy.xpath('//*[@id="day"]').select('14',{force: true});
        cy.xpath('//*[@id="month"]').select('مارس',{force: true});
        cy.xpath('//*[@id="year"]').select('1980',{force: true});
        
        //select city
        cy.xpath('/html/body/app-root/div/div/div/app-demographics-modal/div/div/div/form/div/div[4]/div/div/div/select',{force: true}).select('حلوان');
        //save changes
        cy.get('#demographics-form > div > div:nth-child(6) > div > div > div.col-md-8 > button').click();
        cy.wait(10000);
        cy.contains('الصفحة الشخصية' ,{timeout:10000}).should('be.visible');

    })
```

can i know what is the problem ?

Comment: Can you add an example of the HTML you're working with, as well as the specific error message you receive?

Comment: to debug selector in cypress you can use browser integrated console to select the item based on the xpath. But you need to know that the best practice to select element is using data-test-id if you are the developer of the site, you can add data-test-id to the element.

Comment: I haven't got any errors. Test case passed with no errors but no selection happens using those commands : cy.xpath('//*[@id="day"]').select('14',{force: true});
    cy.xpath('//*[@id="month"]').select('مارس',{force: true});
    cy.xpath('//*[@id="year"]').select('1980',{force: true});